# Enterprise App Distribution (Wi-Fi) says "Could not download app" sometimes

Tags: iphone

We have an iPhone app developed in-house and distributed over wi-fi following [apples docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html)

About 60% of the employees devices can download the app without any problem. For 40%, the installation process stops at 75% and the message *"Could not download app"* is shown.

Anybody experienced this or know how to get a more descriptive error message?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get this sometimes when the device does not have the correct OS version.  For example if you set your minimum OS to 5.1 you will get this error on any device with 5.0 or lower os version.

Also if you have a device which is getting the failed install, you can plug it into your development machine and then in the Xcode organiser select the device and click the console window, run the install and the details of whats happening will appear in the console

Comment: Thank you! This really seems to be the problem. The console window-trick was very helpful.